# docker-lambda sqlalchemy select with no result

Tags: python, docker, lambda

I have a program in aws lambda, and it works very will
But when I put it in docker-lambda:python2.7 something may wrong with it.

It just like:

```
    from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
    select_one_query = "SELECT top 100 * FROM bil_table WHERE 
    recorddate='2017-11-28'"
    engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    try:
        result = engine.execute(
            text(select_one_query).execution_options(autocommit=True))
        records = result.fetchall()
        result.close()
        rowcount = len(records)
        print rowcount
    except Exception:
        raise
```

when run on aws lambda or on ubuntu server, it prints `100`;

but when run docker-lambda with docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task/ lambci/lambda:python2.7 handlers.my_function, it prints `0`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem
The sqlalchemy I down from aws lambda may not like the sqlalchemy of python2.7.12 of the docker-lambda.
I install a new python2.7.12 by pyenv in my server, and pip install sqlalchemy, exchange the sqlalchemy, mssql.so, pymssql.so down from aws lambda,then it works, get the records